# signInWithEmailAndPassword firebaseAuth can't detect wrong password and email

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

When I enter the wrong password or wrong email, the login function does not detect the error, meaning it does not give that there is an error in the password or email. But when I enter the email and the correct password, the function works and goes to the home page. Note that the account registration function works correctly, only the error in the login function.

The console message :

> I/FirebaseAuth( 8740): Logging in as alhrynyansq@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
> W/System  ( 8740): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
> E/RecaptchaCallWrapper( 8740): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS ]

the sign in code page:

```
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';

import 'package:fbproject/custom/custombutton.dart';
import 'package:fbproject/custom/customtextfield.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  //
  //controller for text form field
  TextEditingController semail = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController spassword = TextEditingController();
//
  //
  //global key variable
  GlobalKey<FormState> formstate = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Form(
          key: formstate,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              //
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 60,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "images/logoe.png",
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              //
              Customtextfield(
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val == "") {
                      return "empty";
                    }
                  },
                  mycontroller: semail,
                  hint_text: "email@gmail.com",
                  securetext: false,
                  labelname: "Email",
                  prficon: Icons.person),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              //
              Customtextfield(
                validator: (val) {
                  if (val == "") {
                    return "empty";
                  }
                },
                mycontroller: spassword,
                hint_text: "Password",
                securetext: true,
                labelname: "Password",
                prficon: Icons.password,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              //
              custombtn(
                  textname: "Login",
                  onpressed: () async {
                    if (formstate.currentState!.validate()) {
                      try {
                        final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: semail.text, password: spassword.text);
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("home");
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                          print('==========No user found for that email.');
                        } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                          print(
                              '=======Wrong password provided for that user.');
                        }
                      }
                    } else {
                      AwesomeDialog(
                        context: context,
                        dialogType: DialogType.error,
                        animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                        title: 'خطأ',
                        desc:
                            ' لا يمكن ترك حقل اسم المستخدم أو كلمة المرور فارغ',
                        // btnCancelOnPress: () {},
                        btnOkOnPress: () {},
                      ).show();
                    }
                  }),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              //
              //
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Text(
                        "Login with Google",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Image.asset(
                        "images/google.png",
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
              ),
              //
              //
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Text(
                    "If you don't have an account ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    child: Text(
                      "Sgin Up",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("signup");
                    },
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your password is at least 6 characters in length

Comment: If password less than 6 character , the catching code e.code must return the password error !

Comment: And when I enter  wrong email address and correct password the same exception appeared.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing.  It is not giving specific error messages.

Comment: Found the answer here, it is by design:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249904/i-dont-get-error-codes-of-firebase-auth-in-my-flutter-app-i-only-get-invalid-l