# I Don't get Error codes of Firebase Auth in my Flutter App (I ONLY get INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

when i use FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword() in my Flutter/Dart code, to test scenarios where users, for example, enter a wrong password or wrong email and etc. To get error codes, like: 'user-not-found', 'invalid-email', 'user-disabled' or 'wrong-password'. The problem is that the only error code that i get is 'INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS'.

This is my code:

```
  Future<AuthResult> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      
      return AuthResult.success;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.code);

      switch (e.code) {
        case 'user-not-found':
          
          return AuthResult.userNotFound;
        case 'invalid-email':
          
          return AuthResult.invalidEmail;
        case 'user-disabled':
          
          return AuthResult.userDisabled;
        case 'wrong-password':
          
          return AuthResult.wrongPassword;
        default:
          
          return AuthResult.failure;
      }
    } catch (_) {
      
      return AuthResult.aborted;
    }
  }
```

I also looked on the StackOverFlow and Github, to see if other people had this problem. and it looks like it has to do with email enumeration protection. I looked into the Google Cloud docs to see how to disable this, but this didn't solve my problem, when following the instructions.

Link on how to disable it: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable

This is the error in the Google Cloud console i get, when following the instructions:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.cloud.identitytoolkit.admin.v2.ProjectConfigService.UpdateConfig"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You should note that if the person trying to sign in is a malicious user, and you tell them that the email address definitely exists or not, then you have given them information about how to further attack your system. You should simply tell them that the pair of email/password is not valid so that they don't have much more information than when they started attacking your app.  Please protect the privacy of your users and don't disclose account information to attackers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Firebase projects created since September 15 2023, the setting to protect against email enumeration is enabled by default. This setting makes it harder for malicious user to find out what users are in your project by changing the responses of some APIs, and disabling other APIs completely.

What you're seeing is the result of this setting, which is documented on this page on [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#overview).

That page also shows [how to disable email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable) so that the API reverts to its previous behavior. Note that doing so will make your project/users susceptible to the risks of an email enumeration attack.

Comment: Okay, I understand. So, how would you suggest showing users if there is something wrong with what they have entered?

Comment: That depends. If you want to protect them from email enumeration attacks, you'll have to be intentionally vague about the problem - pretty much exactly as the API does. You could store the necessary information to display a better message elsewhere, but you'd then have to take care to protect it - otherwise you might just as well turn off email enumeration protection.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen according to this, then it's also not really possible to link providers.  Example, user signs in with Google.  Later attempts log in with email And password, we call fetchSignInMethodsForEmail, check for google, and then if google exists attempt to link to google.  

That functionality is disabled (fetchSignInMethodsForEmail) and can no longer link accounts this way.  

Is there a new way to link accounts or is it basically considered insecure due to enumeration attacks?

Comment: There is indeed a problem with account linking in the new flow. The engineering team is investigating, but I'd recommend opening a new question for that - or a [support case](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to make it clear that you're blocked by this.

Comment: This answer should be marked as it correctly responds the op's doubt. @MohammedJamal use the INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS enum instead.

Comment: This is a few months late, but I just ran into this same issue. @JeffPadgett this functionality can be specified within the firebase dashboard. Under Authentication go to Settings and User account linking > Link accounts that use the same email. I've not had any issue with the new firebase version in using this feature. (I'm sure you probably figured this out, but in case other's come along and read it)

Answer (score 2):

This is how to apply the solution from the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77250121/7733418

[image: Screenshot of how to apply solution from existing other answer]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35496827)