# Firebase Authentication Error Handling in iOS Apps

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two iOS applications with identical code for handling login errors. Specifically, the code is:

```
 class func loginUserWith(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ isEmailVerified: Bool) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authDataResult, error) in
        if error == nil {
           // if authDataResult!.user.isEmailVerified ||  !authDataResult!.user.isEmailVerified {
            if authDataResult!.user.isEmailVerified  {
                FirebaseListener.shared.downloadPublicUserFromFirebase(userId: authDataResult!.user.uid, email: email) { error, isEmailVerified in
                    if let error = error {
                        showErrorMessage(message: error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    else {
                        if let currentUser = PublicUser.currentUser() {
  
                            if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
                               let currentSceneDelegate = scene.delegate as? SceneDelegate {

                                let userListener = currentSceneDelegate.listenForCurrentUserChanges(userId: currentUser.objectId) { error in
                                    if let error = error {
                                        print("Error setting up user listener: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    } else {
                                        print("User listener set up successfully for \(currentUser.objectId)")
                                    }
                                }
                       
                                FirestoreListenersManager.shared.addListener(userListener)
  
                                FirebaseListener.shared.downloadCurrentUserBadgesFromFirebase(userId: currentUser.objectId) { error in
                                    if let error = error {
                                        showErrorMessage(message: error.localizedDescription)
                                    }
                                    else {
                                       let badgeListener = currentSceneDelegate.listenForCurrentBadgeChanges(userId: currentUser.objectId) { error in
                                           if let error = error {
                                               print("Error setting up user badge listener: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                           } else {
                                               print("User badge listener set up successfully for \(currentUser.objectId)")
                                           }
                                       }
                                   
                                        FirestoreListenersManager.shared.addListener(badgeListener)
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        }
         
                    }

                    completion(error, isEmailVerified)
                }
            } else {
                print("Email not verified")
                completion(error, false)
            }
        } else {
            completion(error, false)
        }
    }
}

 @IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, !email.isEmpty,
             let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty else {
           showErrorMessage(message: "All fields are required")
           return
       }

       PublicUser.loginUserWith(email: email, password: password) { (error, isEmailVerified) in
           ProgressHUD.show()
           if let error = error {
               let error2:NSError = error as NSError
               print(error2.code)
               print(error)
               showErrorMessage(message: error.localizedDescription)
               ProgressHUD.dismiss()
           } else {
               self.handleEmailVerificationStatus(isVerified: isEmailVerified)
           }
       }
}
```

When testing invalid login credentials:

App (1) prints this error:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x283be9f80 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x283b93f30 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 224, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
code = 400;
errors =     (
            {
        domain = global;
        message = "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS";
        reason = invalid;
    }
);
message = "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS";
```

}}}}

App (2) prints:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17011 "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND}
```

Both apps have the same Firebase SDK version, operate on the same network, and have identical code implementations. Why does one app display the "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS" message nested inside an "An internal error has occurred..." error while the other directly indicates the user doesn't exist with "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier..."? Specifically, I want to display the error to the user and app (2) displays the correct error while app (1) displays "An internal error has occurred...", these are the returned strings from print(error) inside loginButtonPressed. Why are they different?

Answer (score 4):

Since September 15, 2023 Firebase protects new projects against email enumeration attacks by default. With this protection enabled, some APIs return different (less specific) error codes, so that it becomes harder for malicious users to figure out what email addresses exist in the project.

So if one project was created before September 15 and one was created since then, that'd explain the difference in behavior. You can either update the code to handle the more vague error codes, or you can [disable email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable) to get back the old behavior.

Also see:

- [I Don't get Error codes of Firebase Auth in my Flutter App (I ONLY get INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249904/i-dont-get-error-codes-of-firebase-auth-in-my-flutter-app-i-only-get-invalid-l/77250121#77250121)
- the Firebase documentation on [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection)