# Flutter/Firebase Authentication with Email & Password not functioning as intended

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

So I'm trying to make a simple app using Flutter, where I'm using Firebase to authenticate users Emails and Passwords to sign into the app.

Where it's going wrong is that users can sign in - which indicates to me that Firebase is working but when I try to do a try catch statement where I tell the user if they inputted their email or passwords wrong, it doesn't react at all.

I have `import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';` imported

Here is the SignUserIn function:

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  // text editing controllers
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  // sign user in method
  void signUserIn() async {
    // show loading circle
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );

    // try sign in
    try {
      final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );
      // pop the loading circle
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // pop the loading circle
      Navigator.pop(context);
      // Incorrect e-mail
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        // show error to user
        wrongEmailMessage();
      }
      // Incorrect password
      else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        // show error to user
        wrongPasswordMessage();
      }
    }
  }
```

This is wrongEmailMessage()

```
void wrongEmailMessage() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Incorrect Email',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Here is where I call it - on button press

```
           SignInBlock(
              onTap: signUserIn,
            ),
```

I called the wrongEmailMessage() in my SignInBlock and it did work so my only theory is something to do with Firebase isn't right.

Are there some common issues that I'm missing to spot? If any more information is needed I will provide it.

I've tried just printing to the console instead of calling the function still didn't work. I have tried using different e.codes == "" with no avail. When I click the SignInBlock button it works when I have the information written in correctly but when I don't the try do doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Firebase projects created since September 15, [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) is enabled by default. While this protects your users from abuse, it the API doesn't distinguishes between `user-not-found` and `wrong-password` anymore and instead throws a more generic error that is less susceptible to abuve.

You can either update the code to handle the more vague error codes, or you can [disable email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable) to get back the old behavior.

Also see my answer here: [Firebase Authentication Error Handling in iOS Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77253288/firebase-authentication-error-handling-in-ios-apps/77254022#77254022) and [I Don't get Error codes of Firebase Auth in my Flutter App (I ONLY get INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249904/i-dont-get-error-codes-of-firebase-auth-in-my-flutter-app-i-only-get-invalid-l/77250121#77250121)