# Firebase sign in with email and password in Swift is giving internal error

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000e00540 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000e545d0 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 224, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
code = 400;
errors =     (
            {
        domain = global;
        message = "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS";
        reason = invalid;
    }
);
message = "INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS";
```

This error message pops up when I try to sign in using a wrong email and password. All other cases of errors are working and I have checked and redownloaded my .plist file.
When I try to show the error to the user by doing `error.localisedDescription`, it shows the Internal error message. How can I show that the login credentials are invalid.

Comment: Firebase already has a list of error codes it shows if credentials are wrong which can be seen here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#autherrorcodes
Could you show some more code so that we can know what's actually going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a response to this question. Link:

[Firebase Authentication Error Handling in iOS Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77253288/firebase-authentication-error-handling-in-ios-apps)

You have to disable the email enumeration protection using this link
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable