# Firebase authentication : Details of the error message: "auth/internal-error"

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I used the firebase app for authentication in my Angular App, my problem is that I have the error message "auth/internal-error" for several types of errors, wrong password, number of times exceeded, email already in use, I don't know how to differentiate between these cases. Do you have an idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you catch an error from a Firebase Authentication operation, check the error code to differentiate between different types of errors. For example, in Angular:

```html
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

// ...

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

// ...

this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(userCredential => {
    // User successfully signed in
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle different types of errors
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'auth/wrong-password':
        // Handle wrong password error
        console.log('Invalid password');
        break;
      case 'auth/user-not-found':
        // Handle user not found error
        console.log('User not found');
        break;
      case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
        // Handle email already in use error
        console.log('Email already in use');
        break;
      // Add more cases as needed
      default:
        // Handle other errors
        console.error(error.message);
    }
  });
```

Here the error.code property is used to differentiate between different error scenarios. You can find a list of common error codes in the Firebase documentation:

[Firebase auth Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth)

By handling errors in this way, you can provide a better user experience by giving appropriate feedback to users based on the specific issues they encounter during the authentication process.

Comment: Hey Ajay, while this code works when Firebase Authentication returns those error codes, its behavior has changed recently. When you create a new project since September 15, 2023 - protection against email enumeration attacks is enabled by default and you'll get different (less specific) error codes. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249904/i-dont-get-error-codes-of-firebase-auth-in-my-flutter-app-i-only-get-invalid-l/77250121#77250121) and the links I included for more info.

Comment: thanks Ajay for answer, in fact, for the two error messages: "auth/wrong-password" and "auth/user-not-found" I receive the same code: "auth/internal-error"