# Why is firebase throwing non standard error codes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

The error codes thrown while using the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method of `FirebaseAuth` class seem to be different from what is specified in the docs.

I'm handling errors as:

```dart
                      try {
                        final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email, password: password);
                        if (context.mounted) {
                          GlobalSnackBar.show(context,
                              "User logged in!");
                        }
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                        switch (e.code) {
                          case "invalid-email":
                            if (context.mounted) {
                              GlobalSnackBar.show(
                                  context, "Error: email is not valid");
                            }
                            break;
                          case 'wrong-password':
                            if (context.mounted) {
                              GlobalSnackBar.show(
                                  context, "Error: wrong password");
                            }
.
.
.
```

when I login with wrong password the error code that I get is `INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS` instead of the `wrong-password` as described in the [pub-dev docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249904/i-dont-get-error-codes-of-firebase-auth-in-my-flutter-app-i-only-get-invalid-l