# FirebaseAuthUI issue keeps trying to sign me up instead of logging in when trying to use email on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm developing an Android application using Firebase Authentication UI as auth provider, I've enabled both email/password and Google login on the Firebase console but for some reason when I write my email and click next it goes to the sign up window instead of asking my password, and if I fill the form and press save it says there's an error with my email address (because it already is in the DB). The google authentication is working fine. I've followed the google guide step by step but it still doesn't work.

I tried to login with the FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword() method and it works just fine. I tried to execute one of the given examples and it has the same problem.

This is the code generating the problem:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI
import com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract
import com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract()
    ) { res ->
        this.onSignInResult(res)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "User is not logged in")
            signIn()
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "User is already logged in")
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        val providers = arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        )

        val signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .setAlwaysShowSignInMethodScreen(true)
            .build()
        signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
    }

    private fun onSignInResult(res: FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult) {
        when (res.resultCode) {
            RESULT_OK -> {
                // Successfully signed in
                val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            }

            RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                // Sign in canceled
            }

            else -> {
                // Sign in failed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this functionality may currently be broken when email enumeration protection is enabled on your project, which is the default for projects that were created on September 15, 2023 or later. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249904/i-dont-get-error-codes-of-firebase-auth-in-my-flutter-app-i-only-get-invalid-l/77250121#77250121) for more on that, and a link on how to disable that protection.

Comment: Thank you very much, disabling email enumeration made the trick. Thank you man really, should i open an issue on AuthUI-Android github repository to report this problem and the temporary solution?

Comment: If there is no issue in the repo for it yet, please add one indeed.